# is it possible to change only one attribute in the style props in material-ui

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

[material-ui](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/card) provides a way to change the style of a component, via the
style props:

```
  <Card style={ {display:this.state.show} }  >
    <CardHeader
      title="Some Card"
      subtitle="Old"
    />
```

But this will remove all the previous default style for the card, is
it possible to change only one attribute in this case the 'display' attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  Since the style prop will accept an object, you can create an object dynamically and use that.

Example:

```
import objectAssign = require('object-assign');

render() {
  const baseStyle = { color: 'black', fontSize: '20px' };
  const cardStyle = objectAssign({}, baseStyle,
    (this.state.show ? { color: 'red' } : {});
  return (
    <Card style={ cardStyle }>
      <CardHeader ... />
    </Card>
  );
}
```

Comment: good idea but one issue, my problem is that i have no idea what the defaults are for a given component, wont this require that i keep a record of the defaults in `baseStyle`?  and is it possible to programatically access the already existing defaults instead of replacing them? is this possible?

Comment: In that case you can just remove baseStyle in the objectAssign call